# Is it possible to upgrade Nissan Connect firmware?

Tags: nissan

I've a new Nissan Note Acenta. With my VIN, I can deduce that it was produced on 2014 in the UK.

It has a Nissan Connect system (without camera, so no Around View Monitor, Safety Shield system, etc.), but I'm not sure which version it is.

I guess it is a Nissan Connect 1, because I can connect my phone (a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini), but I can not install any app on the car, and I have heard that there are app like Google Search, Facebook, TripAdvisor, etc...

The only services that I can get on the car are the info service like weather, cost of gasoline, etc., but when I want to use it, the system make a voice call to a phone number to retrieve the information, instead of using the internet connection of my mobile phone.

Moreover I've installed the Nissan Connect android app on the Samsung, but it says that the vehicle is not connected even if it is (I can do for instance free hands call, audio streaming and so on). On the Nissan Connect there is also Google send-to-car service, but it does not work.

**So I guess that I'm using Nissan Connect version 1, is it possible on a new 2014 Nissan Note? And is it possible to upgrade to Nissan Connect version 2?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Nissan website.

> Can prior model year vehicles be upgraded with new software that is compatible with NissanConnectSM with Mobile Apps?
>
> No

This may or may not answer your question because it's according to model year.

[Here is the page the data was pulled from.](http://www.nissanusa.com/connect/faq)